# download multiple images from every repeater in single button click

Tags: asp.net

I take  repeater to show images from database I show multiple images and now I want to download that all images on single button click event from repeater

```html
  <asp:Repeater ID="rept1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <a href="../images/<%#Eval(" driver_photo ") %> "download> <img src="../images/<%#Eval("driver_photo  ") %>"  style=" Height:140px; Width:130px; " />
      <br /><br />
      <span class="fa fa-download btn btn-info" aria-hidden="true">
      <b>   Download</b></span></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</td>
```

Comment: You can't do that this way, instead you can write .ashx and take image list to zip in memory array and let user download

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: i don't know about .ashx can you give me another option in simple way.....

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/how-to-download-files-from-server-to-client-using-a-generic-handler/)

Comment: that code is not working here. i used multiple repeater for multiple images and only one butoon click download all that images how can we do that?